# Convert from JMockit to Mockito framework

Tags: junit, mockito, jmockit

I have seen a few examples of people switching from Mockito to JMockit, but I am doing the opposite.  I am not really sure what to do with the @Mocked parameters.  Do these just become @Mock instance variables? I think the NonStrictExpectations clause should become "when" clauses like:

```
when(rpManager.login()).thenReturn(true);
```

and the Verifications section becomes "verify" clauses.

This is an example of a full test case I am converting.

```
@Test
public void testGetOffersUnsuccessfulResponse(@Mocked final RPRequest mockRequest, @Mocked final RPResponse mockResponse) {

    final String sessionId = "123";

    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        rpManager.login(); returns(true);
        rpManager.newRequest(anyString); returns(mockRequest);
        mockRequest.sendRequest(); returns(mockResponse);
        mockResponse.isSuccess(); returns(false);
    }};

    final EpiphanyConnection connection = new EpiphanyConnection(getDummyConnectionProperties(), getDummyActionMapping());
    assertTrue(connection.connect());

    final InteractionContext interactionContext = new InteractionContext();
    interactionContext.setRequestContext(new RequestContext());
    interactionContext.getRequestContext().setAction(getDummyActionMapping().keySet().iterator().next());

    interactionContext.setUserContext(new UserContext());
    interactionContext.getUserContext().setSessionId(sessionId);

    final OfferTranslator offerTranslator = connection.fetchCommunications(interactionContext);
    assertNotNull(offerTranslator);

    new Verifications() {{

        // failure in the below likely indicates mismatched JSON string.
        mockRequest.setData("SessionId", sessionId);
        mockRequest.sendRequest(); times=1;
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito, you are correct there, does not expect any `when` clause to be actually needed. Like the name implies, WHEN this and that happens, then do something - if it did not happen, then that's ok as well.

To make sure that something has actually been called, use `verify`.

`@Mock` will create a mocked instance, correct:

```
@Mock
private MyService service; // will result in a mocked "MyService" instance
```

Don't forget to either call `MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);` or to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`  to make sure the annotations are actually used.

Comment: I understand that part.  I am not sure what to do about the parameters JMockit allowed as well as JMockit specific annotations like @Cascading

Comment: `@Cascading` behavior can be done by using the apropriate default answer for the `@Mock` annotation (or the `Mockito.mock` call). Seems to me that for `@Cascading`, the best Mockito equivalent would be `Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS`. See the mockito doc which has some nice stuff: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_MOCKS

Comment: In my situation, I found that `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)` was what I needed to do for `@Cascading`

Comment: Well, there is an answer for everything in Mockito. Literally. ;-)

Comment: Good, because I have another issue I am about to post a question about! :-)